# How to use jackson key serializers in a map of maps

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize a java object structure to JSON with Jackson 2.5 and I am running into the following issue with key serializers:

```
class MainContainer {
    private final Map<String, Object> entries;
}

class Item {
    // a lot of attributes
}

class ItemMapKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Item> {
     // serialize an item into something simple for map keys
}

class IntermediateContainer {
     private final Map<Item, ... > someMapping;
}
```

I register ItemMapKeySerializer as a SimpleModule in the ObjectMapper. When I add ItermediateContainer to MainContainer, the ItemMapKeySerializer is used. When I add a Map with Item as keys directly into MainContainer, ItemMapKeySerializer is not used and I am not sure why.

This code:

```
MainContainer.add("test", new IntermediateContainer(Map.of(new Item(), ...)));
```

Leads to this JSON:

```
 entries: {
    "test": {
        someMapping: {
            "my nice item 1": {
            ...
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

Whereas this code:

```
MainContainer.add("test", Map.of(new Item(), ...));
```

Leads to this JSON:

```
 entries: {
    "test": {
        Item@12D23: {  // This kind of fieldname is not desired
        ...
        }             
    }
}
```

So when I use a Map as a value in a Map, the key serializer does is not used, but that is what I would like to happen. Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Benni

Answer (score 0):

You should add "toString()" method to your Item. For instance I checked for this example:

```
public static class Item {
    private String val1;
    private int val2;

    public Item(String val1, int val2) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Item && toString().equals(obj.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return toString().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "val1=" + val1 + ",val2=" + val2;
    }
}
```

This gives me such JSON string for simple map wiht Item("AAA", 123) pointing to "Super!":

```
{"val1=AAA,val2=123":"Super!"}
```

You can even go further and use ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString in Item.toString to produce JSON representation of Item for key text.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Jackson-databind from 2.5 to 2.8 resolves that issue and the key serializers are picked up correctly for nested maps.